# Simplifying switch statement (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement, uipickerview

I am trying to simplify a switch-statement that takes a lot of space and time to write. Se the code, you'll understand. If not, I'll explain later.

```
// When row is selected
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerTimer didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.0");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.1");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.2");
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.3");
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.4");
            break;
        case 5:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.5");
            break;
        case 6:
            NSLog(@"It obviously worked.6");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"It did kindof work.NIL");
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way of simplifying this? Just do like,

```
NSLog(@"It did work! %@", row);
```

For the record, I tried that, and it did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format specifier for an integer is `%d` — `%@` specifies an object. To be safe, you should also cast the NSInteger to an `int` when you pass it to `printf()` (so you would write `@"%d", (int)row`), because the size of NSInteger is not guaranteed to be the size the `%d` specifier tells `printf()` to expect.

Incidentally, you don't need to repeat it for each case statement. Without a break, control will fall through to the next case.

Comment: Hah, I'm such a noob..
Is there any overview over such things as format specifiers somewhere?
Thank you :)

Comment: Just do a search on C printf, it'll not list %@ but it has everything else.

Comment: @Emil: This link contains all supported format specifiers for Core Foundation: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265.

Comment: Chuck: According to @dreamlax's link, you ought to cast NSInteger to `long` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Like Chuck said you can do...

```
NSLog(@"It did work! %d", row);
```

...or you can get fancy and turn it into an object...

```
NSLog(@"It did work! %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:row]);
```